# Thread with and without a memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I'm stuck with a c++ assignment where I should make a simple thread and another thread that has the same logic but also have a memory leak.

This should just be an easy thread example, even not doing anything useful in itself. So I guess my question is, what is the easiest thread that can be made in c++ and if I have understood correctly that to make it leak memory, I should make a variable, that is never deleted?
Also should this "leak" be placed in a loop or made to repeat in some other fashion...because for me just leaving one variable undeleted doesn't seem like a major leak.

Comment: What OS? Are you allowed to use any libs? Which version of C++?

Comment: windows (7) would be preferred, everything is allowed...but the simpler the better... i'm not sure about the c++ version but i'm using  microsoft visual c++ 2010 express

Comment: One of the native ways is `CreateThread` but i'd also recommend `boost::thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be enough for a leak:

```
new char;
```

You can place it in a loop if you want more, but be careful -

```
while( true ) {
    new char;
}
```

brings most systems to a halt quite quickly - they start swapping and become barely usable. IMO you should stick to leaking a couple of objects unless you have other specific requirements.

Comment: thanks, this while loop was enough to throw an error about memory running out, but I would also like to know how to construct a thread "around" this while.

Answer (score 0):

You could always allocate a large object (such as a big buffer) and never free it; that way a single allocation would be a substantial memory leak.

As well, if you had a thread that was designed as some kind of frequently called worker thread and had a small memory leak there, over the runtime of your program you could easily run into memory problems through "death of a thousand cuts" style leaks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Boost Thread library, which is probably your easiest option for threads in C++. Yes, a memory leak is just an undeleted variable. If you don't want a one-variable memory leak, just allocate an array of whatever size you deem necessary. `new char[x]`, where x is how many bytes of memory leakage you want